# Duplicating a gameobject except UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The gameobject I wish to duplicate is a UI > Image attached to a Canvas. Now I have no problem duplicating the game object with the following:

```
                GameObject duplicate = Instantiate(gameObjects[0 + i]);
```

(Note it is part of a loop and adding to an array of gameobjects) However it loses its RectTransform information, Canvas Parent and doesn't work as intended. I've tried a few methods but none have worked so I hope someone knows a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per default gameObjects are instantiated on root level if you don't tell [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) different.

You have to store the parent beforehand

```
var parent = gameObjects[i].transform.parent;
```

and then pass it in as well to

```
GameObject duplicate = Instantiate(gameObjects[i], parent);
```

or alternatively set it afterwards

```
GameObject duplicate = Instantiate(gameObjects[i]);
duplicate.transform.SetParent(parent);
```

Be sure though to not pass an actual prefab in .. it is of course not allowed to set the parent to a prefab ;)